# Terraform AWS S3 - deny to all except specific user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a bucket which I need to restrict to a specific user, I have written the following script but it still seems to allow all users to operate on the bucket.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "vulnerability-scans" {
  bucket = "vulnerability-scans"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "vulnerability-scans" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.vulnerability-scans.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.vulnerability-scans.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "vulnerability-scans" {
  statement {
    principals {
      type = "AWS"
      identifiers = [
        aws_iam_user.circleci.arn,
      ]
    }

    actions = [
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:ListBucket",
    ]

    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.vulnerability-scans.arn,
      "${aws_s3_bucket.vulnerability-scans.arn}/*",
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: So only one user should be allowed?

Comment: What does `operate` mean?

Comment: Oh, and btw you are missing `effect = Allow` from what I can see.

Comment: Yes only `aws_iam_user.circleci.arn` should be allowed the operations specified in the permissions section, but currently all users have access

Comment: Is the policy applied to the bucket? Also, I don't know if you omitted that during the copy/paste but you are missing `effect` in the policy.

Answer (score 7):

I think you have to take into account that other users may have `Allow` in their policies, so the approach here should be to deny access to any users not being the user you want it to be. There is a detailed explanation in the AWS docs [1], but for the sake of brevity, I think the terraform code should look like the following:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "vulnerability-scans" {
  statement {
    sid    = "AllExceptUser"
    effect = "Deny"
    principals {
      type = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }

    actions = [
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:ListBucket",
    ]

    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.vulnerability-scans.arn,
      "${aws_s3_bucket.vulnerability-scans.arn}/*",
    ]

    condition {
      test     = "StringNotLike"
      variable = "aws:userId"
      values = [
        aws_iam_user.circleci.arn
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Even though the reference URL says it is for an IAM role, the same applies for a user. The `StringNotLike` condition operator has more detailed explanation in [2].

---

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_String